# Definite/indefinite articles vs. inflections

Tags: latin, romance-languages, inflection, articles

While some languages have definite/indefinite articles (*a/an/the* in English, *le/la/les* and *un/une/des* in French), others don't (Russian, Latin). In this connection I have a few questions:

1. *Chicken or egg*: are the articles *acquired* or *lost*? Do proto-languages (proto-Indo-European for my examples) have articles or do they vary as well in this respect?
2. Is absence of articles in a complimentary distribution with other grammatical features (e.g., the noun inflection), so that the definiteness can be still expressed?

**Anecdotal evidence** is suggested by Latin vs. Romance languages: the latter acquired the articles but lost the inflections present in Latin. So one could *hypothesize* that the inflected languages communicate the definiteness via their flexible word order. (This is just a hypothesis that I borrowed from some of the answers to [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/739/how-is-definiteness-expressed-in-languages-with-no-definite-article-clitic-or-a). I already see how it could be contradicted, e.g., by the example of German, which is both inflected and has articles).

Comment: How would flexible word order encode definiteness?  (Generally it's the languages with inflexible word order where order encodes information.)

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Like definiteness (or, better, specificity), free word order encodes information structure, this is the link.

Comment: Related: [What does Eastern Aramaic have to say about “(definite) articles are acquired, not lost”?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/35404)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Question 1

As other answers have said, the different articles found in Indo-European languages developed over time. No articles are reconstructed for Proto-Indo-European. I don't know of any European language, or in fact any language in any family, that used to have articles and then lost them.

The Indo-European language that developed a definite article the earliest is Greek. Since Greek lacks an ablative case, Marc's formulation of "(definite) articles show up when the number of cases drop below 5 (not counting vocative)" is I think true as an observation, but I'm not sure it means anything in terms of causation. I can't see why the difference between 5 and 4 cases would be significant here; there are languages such as Hungarian that have articles and more than 5 cases (although Hungarian cases are arguably not entirely comparable to Indo-European cases).

Definite articles developed later in Romance and Germanic languages. The Slavic language [Macedonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macedonian_grammar#Morphology) has also developed a (suffixal) definite article, and like the Romance languages, it has lost case inflection.

Ancient Greek did not have an indefinite article; indefinite articles developed later. All singular indefinite articles that I am familiar are derived from the numeral *one.*

#### Question 2

While it’s true that word order in languages without articles is *sometimes* related to whether a noun phrase is definite or indefinite, I don’t think that is systematic or common enough in article-less languages to be seen as a general “compensatory” factor for the lack of definite and indefinite articles. The thing is, the distinction between the definite and indefinite article is often predictable just from the context: either the identity of the following word, of the head noun, or of the construction in which it is used, or the overall semantics of the sentence—and even when not, it is often not essential information. So even though a fair number of languages have developed highly grammaticalized means of expressing definiteness or indefiniteness, I think it’s probably not right to approach the matter with the assumption that languages *need* to have some way of marking (in)definiteness that is as pervasive as (in)definite articles in languages that have them.

If there is actually a negative correlation between case marking and articles (which I am not sure is true), I would guess that it is more likely because both function to mark the boundaries and categories of words or phrases. The presence of an article, whether definite or indefinite, or of a case ending, whether nominative, accusative, etc., can help a listener identify the edges of noun phrases or of nouns.

Comment: If the articles are not necessary, does it mean that the languages that have them are more complex and/or more redundant?

Comment: @Vadim: "Complexity" is difficult to define, but I think it's clear that a language with multiple articles like English is more complex than something that we could call "English₂" that had the same lexicon and grammar as English but used zero in place of *the* or *a*. (The preceding clause given in English₂: "I think it's clear that language with multiple articles like English is more complex than something that we could call "English₂" that had same lexicon and grammar as English but no articles").

Comment: That is, *all else equal,* having a contrast between different articles adds complexity to the grammar of a language. But when you're comparing two natural languages, all else is never equal. I might be belaboring an obvious point, but I just wanted to make sure I'm clear to avoid giving the misimpression that "languages with articles are in general more complex as a whole than languages without articles": I hope you can see that that *doesn't* follow from what I said in the preceding comment. Articles often contain redundant information; that is true of many, perhaps most grammatical markers

Comment: (plural markers are another example of something that many languages have even though the information they encode is frequently redundant)

Comment: I have a rather naive notion of *complexity conservation*: if a language is simpler in one place (e.g., it has no articles), it is more complex elsewhere - the two phenomena probably being in a complementary distribution.

Comment: @Vadim: There are other people who seem to find that idea appealing too, but as far as I know there isn't a huge amount of evidence for it, and some people have argued to the contrary that languages don't in fact all have equally complex grammatical systems.

Comment: @ewawe “some people have argued to the contrary that languages don't in fact all have equally complex grammatical systems” This is interesting, could you provide some references? Thanks.

Comment: @Atamiri: I was thinking of John McWhorter, but I’m not really familiar with his work

Comment: @Vadim Consider that Russian speaking English and omitting articles is understandable, he just sounds odd.

Comment: @ewawe in my experience (working with many languages that lack articles) human communication still requires a way to express definiteness, so those languages simply use a different method to do this. So a lack of articles really means little.

Comment: I would suggest English  is less complex in this area because it typically *requires* that definiteness be specified. Many languages do not require the specification of definiteness and so make less use of systems to do so. They are therefore more complex as speakers have to decide whether or not to indicate definiteness, and if they don't then hearers have to figure it out from other cues.

Comment: Plus, most English article use has little to do with definiteness; there are hundreds of idioms and fixed phrases that use articles any which way at all, as convenient markers with no meaning. Consider, for instance, the implications of _I dialed **the** wrong number_, which requires a definite article, in a context which is the exact opposite of definiteness.

Answer (score 1):

1) Articles are acquired. Proto-Indo-European didn’t have articles and many Indo-European languages don’t have them until now.

2) This is more complicated. As languages lose case inflection while retaining free word order, they need other means to express grammatical functions. For example, German and some peripheral dialects of Macedonian have both articles and cases but this is not redundant as there’s a high degree of case syncretism in nouns. There are also languages with free word order and without case and articles but these are rather an exception.

Overall, languages need definiteness (and specificity) to express information structure. This can be done by free word order or articles (or morphology but this is very rare). The general pathway is acquiring more rigid word order which is compensated by starting to use articles.

Comment: I am not quite sure of what you mean by *morphology* as opposed to inflection. The articles that attach to nouns?

Comment: Hungarian and Classical Arabic have cases and rather free word order, but still have articles. Romanian has articles and cases which are usually expressed by the forms of the articles.

Comment: @Vadim What I meant is that in some languages information structure is signalled by morphology but this isn’t germane to the present discussion.

Comment: I've never heard of a language with free word order but no case marking (though I can imagine the possibility). Can you provide examples of such languages?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Macedonian, for example. A more exotic example would be Abkhaz.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'd consider them only moderately free word order languages eg within Abkhaz NPs word order is rigid.

Answer (score 1):

As Atamiri said (in Indo-European languages at least), articles are acquired. From what I remember (my degree is from last century), (definite) articles show up when the number of cases drop below 5 (not counting vocative). Not sure of the reference, but I think it is discussed in Gustave Guillaume's *Le problème de l'article et sa solution dans la langue française*.

Interestingly enough, there seems to be a parallel with the development of auxiliary verbs (but that's another story).

(Also, the egg came first, laid by a proto-chicken.)

Comment: Some say that it was a decisive mutation in the egg-cell of the proto-chicken that created a chicken. In reality, the boundaries between species are rather blurred, so there is no one exact moment when the proto-chicken became a chicken.

Comment: @Vadim: indeed.